# Reading long CSV file and separating into multiple tables

Tags: php, sql, database, csv

I have built a database with **6 tables**, roughly **175 fields**. About 130 of these fields are to be populated from data on a **CSV**.

Currently, a handheld device exports this **CSV** and it is read into a spreadsheet but it's moving to a database. So, on the front end when someone uploads a **CSV**, it will populate the database.

**Question:**

I'm trying to figure out the best way to break that **CSV** up line by line and put certain info into certain tables. Is that possible? If so how?

I was hoping I could query to create a `header` for each **CSV** field and map it to database fields (Since the CSV will always be in the same order).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think of it as a RBAR problem.  If you load the file as-is into a single staging table, you can then run something like the following for each table:
INSERT INTO destTable (col1, col2)
SELECT col1, col2
FROM StageTable
WHERE col3 = 'criteria'

That way, you keep everything set-based.  Of course it depends on the number of records involved, but processing data row by row and TSQL are generally not a good fit.  SSIS does a much better job of that than TSQL.

Comment: This makes sense, but I forgot one point. These CSVs will be read in daily, anywhere from 10 to 30 per day. We have 6 tables or so per CSV, where everything is split. So basically just create a staging table where each CSV will be put (all fields) and then have the query push those into the live tables?

Answer (score 0):

tag it by associative array in columns example

id,name,color
1,jo,red
2,ma,blue
3,j,yellow

get the first line in one array, so just compare by index the value in a loop